# R: Classification table for svyglm (survey package)

Tags: r, regression, survey

I trying to do logistic regression  analysis with 'survey' package.

I am struggeling with Classification table of my model.

```
design1 <- svydesign(ids = ~num, weights = ~weights, data = mydata, fpc=~nm, strata = ~strata1)

glm_m<- svyglm(var1 ~ sex + age1 + educat, design = design1, family = quasibinomial())
```

How should I continue to do a Classification table next?
And second, after that calculate a Hosmer-Lemeshow Goodness of Fit (GOF) Test with a survey data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a classification to get a classification table.  Suppose you want a threshold at 0.5. Then `svytable` to get a population table

```
design1<-update(design1, fittedp=fitted(design1))
design1<-update(design1, fittedclass= fittedp>0.5)
svytable(~var1+fittedclass, design1)
```

There are at least [two](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0600600106) [different](http://www.asasrms.org/Proceedings/y2003/Files/JSM2003-000744.pdf) extensions of the Hosmer-Lemeshow test to survey data, but I don't know of an R implementation of either.